# Django Form Submit Button

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a pretty simple file upload form class in django:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    category = forms.ChoiceField(get_category_list())
    file = forms.FileField()
```

one problem is that when i do `{{ form.as_p }}`, It has no submit button. How do i add one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" value="Gogogo!" />
```

Comment: As humorous as this is, it's not a very complete answer. Put that below `{{ form.as_p }}` before you close it off with `</form>`.

Answer (score 6):

This is a template for a minimal HTML form ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#the-template)):

```html
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Put that under `<PROJECT>/templates/MyForm.html` and then replace `'DIRS': []` in `<PROJECT>/<PROJECT>/settings.py` with the following:

```py
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
```

Code like this can then be used to serve your form to the user when he does a GET request, and process the form when he POSTs it by clicking on the submit button ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#the-view)):

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseNotFound
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import forms

def my_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse('Yay valid')
    else:
        form = forms.MyForm()

    return render(request, 'MyForm.html', {'form': form})
```